# What is the price of an empty alchemical capsule?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, alchemy

I've been looking in the Complete Adventurer for the price for empty alchemical capsules (for putting other alchemical stuff / poisons into), but can't find the cost anywhere in the book. What is the price of empty capsules?

I'm not entirely sure, but the way the book describes alchemical capsules it sounds like they're not the same as a glass vial.

Answer (score 2):

#### Probably 1gp just as a common vial.

There is no mention on the capsule as a distinct item, so it is up to the DM.

This said, we can speculate on two hypothesis:

- The empty capsule is part of the materials needed to craft the alchemical concotion. So it can't cost more than 5gp, a third of the price on the cheapest capsule (Table 4–3: Alchemical Capsules on page 121). Our ceiling is less than 5gp.
- A [vial for liquids](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Vial) costs 1gp. It comes with a stopper. **It can be used for a magical potion** so it is a very good vial for 1gp. An empty alchemical capsule shouldn't cost less than a vial. Our floor is 1gp

So the price of the capsule is something between 1gp and 5gp, heavily skewered towards 1gp.

I'd not bother with the price of empty capsules, just assuming they are part of the materials required to craft the alchemical item.

Comment: Well I just needed to figure out what the cost for a alchemical capsule was because you can use poison in them (and i presume various other alchemical substances) via the [triple or single] weapon capsule retainer (but had no indication of the cost to get the item, and has no examples to go off other than alchemic versions). But at least that gives me something to work with thanks. :)